# Different result in computing fundamental matrix by Python and C++ using OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm computing fundamental matrix for video odometry in Python and C++ using OpenCV. I've tried to keep the code in both implementations quite the same. However, I'm getting different results in both. In Python, it works correctly, and in C++ it is showing completely incorrect results. Below is a partial example of their code and outputs (first one in Python and second one in C++)

Python version code:

```
import os
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# Main Function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    K = np.matrix([[522.4825, 0,        300.9989], 
                   [0,        522.5723, 258.1389], 
                   [0.0,      0.0,      1.0]])
img1 = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1] + ".jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread(sys.argv[2] + ".jpg")

# sift = cv2.SURF()

detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SURF")    # SURF, FAST, SIFT
descriptor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF") # SURF, SIFT

# kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
# kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

kp1 = detector.detect(img1)
kp2 = detector.detect(img2) 

k1, des1 = descriptor.compute(img1,kp1)
k2, des2 = descriptor.compute(img2,kp2)

# BFMatcher with default params
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

good = []

# Apply ratio test
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
            good.append(m)

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    F, mask = cv2.findFundamentalMat(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
else:
    print "Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT)
    matchesMask = None

print F
```

And it's output:

```
[[ -3.22706105e-07   1.12585581e-04  -2.86938406e-02]
[ -1.16307090e-04  -5.04244159e-07   5.60714444e-02]
[  2.98839742e-02  -5.99974406e-02   1.00000000e+00]]
```

C++ version here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    //Define intrinsic matrix
    cv::Mat intrinsic = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << 522.4825, 0, 300.9989,
            0, 522.5723, 258.1389,
            0, 0, 1);

    // Read input images
    string jpg1 = argv[1];
    jpg1.append(".jpg");
    string jpg2 = argv[2];
    jpg2.append(".jpg");
    cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread(jpg1,0);
    cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread(jpg2,0);
    if (!image1.data || !image2.data)
        return 0;

    // Display the images
    // cv::namedWindow("Image 1");
    // cv::imshow("Image 1",image1);
    // cv::namedWindow("Image 2");
    // cv::imshow("Image 2",image2);

    // pointer to the feature point detector object
    cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = new cv::SurfFeatureDetector();
    // pointer to the feature descriptor extractor object
    cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor();

    // Detection of the SURF features
    vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
    detector->detect(image1,keypoints1);
    detector->detect(image2,keypoints2);

    // Extraction of the SURF descriptors
    cv::Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
    extractor->compute(image1,keypoints1,descriptors1);
    extractor->compute(image2,keypoints2,descriptors2);

    // Construction of the matcher
    cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> > matcher;

    vector<vector<cv::DMatch> > matches;
    vector<cv::DMatch> good_matches;
    matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, 2);

    for (vector<vector<cv::DMatch> >::iterator matchIterator= matches.begin();
         matchIterator!= matches.end(); ++matchIterator) {
        if ((*matchIterator)[0].distance < 0.7f * (*matchIterator)[1].distance) {
            good_matches.push_back((*matchIterator)[0]);
        }
    }

    // Convert keypoints into Point2f
    vector<cv::Point2f> src_pts, dst_pts;
    for (vector<cv::DMatch>::iterator it= good_matches.begin();
         it!= good_matches.end(); ++it)
    {
        // Get the position of left keypoints
        float x= keypoints1[it->queryIdx].pt.x;
        float y= keypoints1[it->queryIdx].pt.y;
        src_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(x,y));
        // Get the position of right keypoints
        x= keypoints2[it->trainIdx].pt.x;
        y= keypoints2[it->trainIdx].pt.y;
        dst_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(x,y));
    }
    // Compute F matrix using RANSAC
    cv::Mat fundemental = cv::findFundamentalMat(
            cv::Mat(src_pts),cv::Mat(dst_pts), // matching points
            CV_FM_RANSAC,  // RANSAC method
            5.0); // distance
    cout <<  fundemental << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And its output:

```
[-4.310057787788129e-06, 0.0002459670522815174, -0.0413520716270485;
-0.0002531048911221476, -8.423657757958228e-08, 0.0974897887347238;
0.04566865455090797, -0.1062956485414729, 1]
```

Here are two test images:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIWBt.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duzb1.jpg)

I can't find the reason.
Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) may be related, but I am uncertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody is answering I'll share my thoughts. Do you check only numbers in F, or you apply it somehow and observe incorrect results? As @brandon-white has already noticed, floating-point precision may be one of the reasons. But actually it is more complicated.

First thing that comes to mind is that AFAIK in C++ OpenCV uses it's own routines for matrix and other math operations, while in python numpy is used where possible. Maybe under the hood they use similar algorithms/implementations, but still you may get numerically different results, especially in cases where you deal with ambiguity (eigenvector decomposition, SVD, etc).

Also, you are using [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) to estimate F. In order to deal with (theoretically) any amount of outliers RANSAC takes a small random sample from all of your keypoints, and tries to find pairs, that satisfy some constraints. It does this multiple times, and takes a best sample afterwards to calculate a final model. So basically you will end up with different points to estimate F each run, if you seed the pseudo-random generation routine appropriately. But, usually homography and fundamental matrix estimators use a smarter approach, and after a sample that best satisfies the constraints is found - all points that satisfy this model are used to recalculate the matrix again. This way you should get more consistent results, ideally same if RANSAC parameters are OK. I am not sure whether it is used in OpenCV, but I guess it is.

Finally, there are [degenerate cases](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~marc/tutorial/node58.html), where F can't be fully estimated - case of planar motion, when all your keypoint lie on a plane (in 3D world), and purely rotational camera motion. Since you say that your code works in Python this is probably not the case, but still a point to consider.

So if you haven't done so yet - try to check F matrices you get on some data to ensure that the results you get are really different. In that case - there should be an error somewhere (admittedly I haven't closely checked your code yet).

Also, showing the matches you use for F computation may be useful for debugging, since that narrow the range of places, where your code may be behaving differently.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. Today I apply the matrix F into computing rotations in x-y plane between two images, and find it works. Rotation results in C++ and Python appears almost the same, though it seemed not to work last night. Maybe my following code gets something wrong, and the code in this page is correct.

Comment: Glad you fixed it :) It would be great if you'd updated the answer with current code that works, to help other people that may have same issue. Or maybe you used different images as input?